# WordPress Single Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Ребят выводится только заголовок поста а контент не хочет

```
<?php
get_header();
include 'nav.php';
echo $nav;
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/bs/style.css">
<div>
<br>
<div class="backgroundin">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p><?php get_the_content(); ?></p>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: минимум 2 ошибки. 1 - include. 2  get_the_content()

Comment: пардон, 3 ошибки - "подключение" стилей. и не просто стилей а главного файла темы.

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_content();` возвращает контент, а не выводит.

Нужно либо

```
<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
```

либо

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

и не стоит оборачивать контент в параграф, т. к. внутри текст будет разбиваться на них автоматически, если не определено иначе